# Resources for the state design pattern implemented in PHP?

Tags: php, design-patterns

I am looking for resources and examples of the `state design pattern` for `PHP`. Could anybody share these with me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/state/php

Comment: Very helpful, as the example is realistic

Answer (score 1):

And another one:

- [IBM: Five more PHP design patterns](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-php-designpatterns/index.html?ca=drs-tp1308)

You have to scroll down a bit.